# Apple Watch Connectivity file not found

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos, watchconnectivity

When I try to import the `WatchConnectivity` framework like this:

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
```

I get this error:

> 'WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h' file not found

Is there something extra that I had to import or is this a problem with the version of Xcode I have?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have? What version of watchOS are you trying to support?

Comment: I have Version 6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode version 6.4 doesn't support watchOS 2 SDK, which is what would be required to use `WatchConnectivity`.

This is why the `#import` returns a 'file not found' error, as that particular header file (and framework) didn't exist prior to watchOS 2.

You would have to upgrade to Xcode version 7.0 or higher, if you want to use `WatchConnectivity` or other watchOS 2 features.